# Sum symbol multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

I have multi-linear function and I try to prove the identity for her and the basis is at some order $j_1 $ to $j_k$.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l6tT.jpg

And each $x_i$ is written in the form of the basis. I understood that each $x_{1j}$ combines with the next $x_{2j}$ and then $ x_{2j} $combines with every $x_{3j}$. But in the 3rd row do we have multiplication of the sums? Or just sum in the sum? And on the last row the inequality $1 \le j_1 ... j_n \le n$ means we run all permutations and then the x's multiply ?

Answer (score 0):

In the third row you should read this as 
$$\sum_{j_1= 1}^n (x_{1j_1} (\dots )).$$

For the other question, it does not mean that you run over all permutations, but rather over all $n$-tuples. You consider each tuple $(j_1, j_2, \dots, j_n)$ with $1 \le j_i \le n$ and for it the respective expression in the sum, and sum them all together.

Comment: Yes ofcourse we cannot have equal j's

Comment: You can very well have equal $j$'s, this is my point. In a permutation they are all distinct. Here, you can have $(1,1, \dots, 1)$ and $(1,1,2,2 \dots, 2)$ and so on.

Comment: Aha and in the triangular matrix we have only solution because the other permutations contain 0 right :)?

Comment: What you say is correct if your multilinear function is alternating, like the determinant.

Comment: yes that is what I mean

Comment: Good. In this case you can subsequently also restrict just to permutations as tuples where elements are repeated will only contribute $0$. However, it is still true that the last sum is technically over all tuples and not only over all permutations. To restrict to permutations could be a next step of simplification.